# Sending Entity Framework entities over WCF: how to prevent serialization of navigation fields?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, serialization

I have a problem when sending Entity Framework-generated entities with navigation properties over WCF. I have a `Securities` database for storing financial data and two tables inside it:

`Stock : Id, Symbol, CompanyName, ExchangeName`
`Option: Id, StockId, OptionType, Strike`

I created an Entity Framework model for this database. Then I created WCF service which exposes generated `Stock` and `Option` EF entities to the clients.

My generated entity `Stock` has navigation property `EntityCollection<Option> Options`.
When trying to return `Stock` entity from WCF service to the client, I get an `SerializationException`: WCF cannot serialize `Options` navigation property because database connection has been already closed.

I can call `Options.Load()` method when database connection is opened to fill `Options` property, but what should I do if I don't want to load full object graph for `Stock` entity?

Comment: Entities are not for your service layer, even if they are Code-First POCOs, EF mutates them. Save yourself trouble down the road and create separate models/DTOs for your service layer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've fought with this one for a while.

First, I turned lazy loading off.  But I still had problems with cycles in my object graph.
Then, I put `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]` tags on all of my entities.  That worked, but I still had a lot of performance issues do to a denormalized database.
Finally, I broke down and make dtos and I use AutoMapper to populate them.

One of my coworkers told me to do this from the beginning, and I should have just listened to him.  Do yourself a favor and don't make the same mistake that I did.

**Edit**
I forgot to mention that I had issues deserializing entities that has properties of type `ICollection<T>`.  These will deserialize as arrays.  Somehow `T[]` implements `ICollection<T>` but `Add` and `Remove` will throw exceptions.  This was another reason to use DTOs.

Comment: An array (`[]`) cannot be `Add()`ed to in .NET. It's not like a Javascipt array that can be `push()`ed to so that's why you get the error. If it were a `List<T>` it could be

Answer (score 0):

With EF5, not sure with EF4, this might work.  Change the navigation property setter to private.

```
public class OptionEntity
{
    // properties

    // navigation 
    public virtual StockEntity Stock { get; private set; }
}
```