# Non-Virtual properties are initialized even when lazy loading is disabled

Tags: entity-framework-6, lazy-loading, navigation-properties

I have disabled lazy-loading in my Entity Framework db context. But still having issues with following models:

```
public class Currency
{
    //properties
    public ICollection<ConversionRate> ConversionRates{get;set;}

    public Currency()
    {
        ConversionRates = new HashSet<ConversionRate>();
    }
}
```

Conversion Rate class is as follows:

```
public class ConversionRate
{
    [ForeignKey("FromCurrencyId")]
    public Currency FromCurrency { get; set; }

    public Guid FromCurrencyId { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("ToCurrencyId")]
    public Currency ToCurrency { get; set; }

    public Guid ToCurrencyId { get; set; }
}
```

Following are Configuration:

```
///Currency
HasMany(x => x.ConversionRates).WithRequired(x => x.FromCurrency);
HasMany(x => x.ConversionRates).WithRequired(x => x.ToCurrency);
```

When I use following statement to get `ConversionRate`s:

```
var cr = _uow.ConversionRates.Query
           .Include(x=>x.FromCurrency)
           .Include(x=>x.ToCurrency)
           .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x=>x.Id==id);
```

The following collections are populated:

```
cr.FromCurrency.ConversionRates
cr.ToCurrency.ConversionRates
```

What I'm doing wrong that is filling collections?

Answer (score 0):

Your ConversionRates collection needs to be defined as virtual. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#lazy

Comment: Well from same post: **Lazy loading of the Posts collection can be turned off by making the Posts property ***non-virtual***:**

Comment: Sorry, misread. Now that I read it closer you've disabled lazy loading and made the collection non-virtual so isn't that the expected behavior (that the collections are filled)?

Comment: yes, exactly this anomaly is what is puzzling me!!! I am not able to serialize and send it as JSON because of circular reference.

Comment: Maybe automapper could help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501913/sending-entity-framework-entities-over-wcf-how-to-prevent-serialization-of-navi

Comment: Even then it will not help. I'm not copying anything manually from some other object. Getting complete shit from EF itself. There are no complex things to break and copy to simple DTOs.